# How to keep JSON value as String?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

This is the JSON string:

```
{"name":"Chris","home":[],"children":[{"name":"Belle"},{"name":"O"}]}
```

I normally create custom object like this:

```
public class Child
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> home { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Child> children { get; set; }
}
```

But now I don't want children as *List*,

I just want to record/serialize children as String, not Child. Meaning that I just don't mind keeping this part: *[{"name":"Belle"},{"name":"O"}]* as STRING, NOT Array/List.

How can I do that? I am using *DataContractJSONSeriliazer.ReadObject* method.

Comment: I cannot help you with `DataContractJSONSeriliazer` but I had similar need (to keep some part of JSON untouched) with Newtonsoft JSON.net. There I could use `JObject` or `JArray` class as a serialization target to keep a field a plain JSON. Maybe you could find something similar.

Comment: Please see if this could help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943471(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: remove children as a serialize candidate, add a new property childrenstring or similar name, have the get property of the childrenstring return a string from the list of children.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, I don't mind using different library, any sample codes for JSON.net? I like the keep the field a plain JSON maybe. Thanks!! Oh your second suggestion link is not exactly what I need 'cause I have to parse the children. I don't need to parse the children.

Comment: @TravisJ, sounds interesting, can you provide working sample codes? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisLists While you can get the childrens' names as string in a single line of code (`var names = string.Join(",",obj.children.Select(c=>c.name));`), why do you bother with hooking the serialization process. Just write a method that returns the name of children as string. (Of course,  this can be done with Json.Net using a custom JsonConverter but do you really need it?)

Comment: @EZI I am confused by your comment. please provide code or link. :)

Comment: @ChrisLists Could you post the expected JSON result?

Comment: @Win but i am not expecting JSON result though. I just don't need to parse or serialize the children value in the JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't mind using another library I would propose NewtonSoft JSON.NET. There are classes there (`JObject`, `JArray`, etc.) which can represent arbitrary JSON data as a part of some strongly typed object. I was using this in order to deserialize some large JSON that only small part of was interesting to me. I could deserialize whole JSON, modify the part that was important and serialize back, keeping the irrelevant part untouched.

Here is as code sample to get your `children` as string, even though it is an array in JSON. What is important is that you could modify content of other fields (`name` and `home`) and serialize whole thing back, and `children` in JSON output would remain an array with original content.

Assuming

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

here's the code sample:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name;
    public List<object> home;
    public JArray children; // I don't care what children may contain
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceJSON =
          @"{""name"":""Chris"",""home"":[],""children"":[{""name"":""Belle""},{""name"":""O""}]}";
        RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(sourceJSON);
        string partAsString = rootObject.children.ToString(Formatting.None);
        // partAsString is now: [{"name":"Belle"},{"name":"O"}]
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!, exactly what I am looking for. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding of your question, you can use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), and add a dummy property.

[image]

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"name\":\"Chris\",\"home\":[],\"children\":[{\"name\":\"Belle\"},{\"name\":\"O\"}]}";

        RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "home")]
    public List<object> Home { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "children")]
    public List<Child> ChildrenCollection { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Children
    {
        get
        {
            // You can format the result the way you want here. 
            return string.Join(",", ChildrenCollection.Select(x => x.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The other answer works perfectly for me in this case. I hope others will find your answer useful.

Comment: I'm glad that you figure out. Honestly, I like Kuba Wyrostek's answer more than mine.